# Asignar alarma creada a una mascota ya existente (Android Java)

Tags: java, android

Os cuento mi problema: tengo una clase llamada "Pets" para registrar mascotas, esta clase tiene una lista de alarmas para añadir alarmas y recordatorios a estas mascotas:

```
package com.isaac.appet.HomeFragment;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.Serializable;

import io.realm.RealmList;
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;

public class Pets extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey
    long id;
    public String petType;
    private String petName;
    private String petUrlImage;
    private RealmList<Alarms> alarms = new RealmList<>();

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPetType() {
        return petType;
    }

    public void setPetType(String petType) {
        this.petType = petType;
    }

    public RealmList<Alarms> getAlarms() {
        return alarms;
    }

    public void setAlarms(RealmList<Alarms> alarms) {
        this.alarms = alarms;
    }

    public String getPetUrlImage() {
        return petUrlImage;
    }

    public void setPetUrlImage(String petUrlImage) {
        this.petUrlImage = petUrlImage;
    }

    public String getPetName() {
        return petName;
    }

    public void setPetName(String petName) {
        this.petName = petName;
    }

}
```

He creado un formulario para añadir alarmas a estas mascotas, el problema es que creo que estoy haciendo algo mal, porque cuando agrego la mascota y hago clic en ella para ver qué alarmas tiene, me muestra las mismas alarmas en todas las mascotas. El siguiente extracto de código es el evento "onClick" para guardar la alarma:

```
btnSaveAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            realm.beginTransaction();

            Alarms alarm = new Alarms();

            alarm.setTitle(etAlarmTitle.getText().toString());
            alarm.setTime(etAlarmTime.getText().toString());
            alarm.setDesc(etAlarmDesc.getText().toString());

            Number maxId = realm.where(Alarms.class).max("id");
            long nextID;

            if (maxId == null) {
                nextID = 1;
            } else {
                nextID = maxId.longValue() + 1;
            }

            alarm.setId(nextID);

            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(alarm);
            realm.commitTransaction();

            finish();

        }
    });
```

Este código funcionaba de tal manera que cuando presionaba una mascota me mostraba las alarmas de esa mascota:

```
adapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = adapter.getPositionFromView(v);
                Pets pressPet = pets.get(position);

                RealmResults<Alarms> results = realm.where(Alarms.class).findAll();

                alarms.clear();
                alarms.addAll(pressPet.getAlarms());


               adapterAlarms.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Y finalmente os dejo la clase "Alarmas" a través de la cual creo las alarmas:

```
    package com.isaac.appet.HomeFragment;

import java.io.Serializable;

import io.realm.RealmList;
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;

public class Alarms extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey
    long id;
    RealmList<Pets> namePetAlarm;
    String title;
    String desc;
    String time;

    public long getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }

    public RealmList<Pets> getNamePetAlarm() {
        return namePetAlarm;
    }

    public void setNamePetAlarm(RealmList<Pets> namePetAlarm) {
        this.namePetAlarm = namePetAlarm;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

}
```

Es como si estuviera creando alarmas para todas las mascotas y por eso me las muestra todas, pero no sé en qué momento algo debería cambiar. Espero que podáis ayudarme. Muchísimas gracias.

Saludos.